# Problem in erasing element in list

Tags: c++

```
struct ScheduleTaskInfo
{
unsigned int nTaskID;
   __time64_t timeStartTime;
__time64_t timeEndTime; 
};

typedef list<ScheduleTaskInfo> SchedulerList;   

SchedulerList::iterator itrSchedulerList;    
for(itrSchedulerList = gSchedulerList.begin();itrSchedulerList != gSchedulerList.end();itrSchedulerList++)
{
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetLocalTime(&st);

    CTime ctSyatemTime(st);

    if (itrSchedulerList->timeEndTime == ctSyatemTime.GetTime())
    {

        itrSchedulerList = gSchedulerList.erase(itrSchedulerList);          
    }

}
```

I am doing this it is crashing in for loop.I think it is due to erase();
Am I doing something wrong here??Please suggest me on this

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: What line does the segmentation fault originate from? and what is the error?

Comment: for(itrSchedulerList = gSchedulerList.begin();itrSchedulerList != gSchedulerList.end();itrSchedulerList++) Here I am getting debug assertion failed in vs 2008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write `itrSchedulerList++` in `else-block` as:

```
for(itrSchedulerList = gSchedulerList.begin();
                     itrSchedulerList !=gSchedulerList.end();)
{
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetLocalTime(&st);

    CTime ctSyatemTime(st);

    if (itrSchedulerList->timeEndTime == ctSyatemTime.GetTime())
    {

        itrSchedulerList = gSchedulerList.erase(itrSchedulerList);          
    }
    else
        itrSchedulerList++;
}
```

This ensures that you don't increment it beyond end of the list. `erase()` might return end iterator which will be incremented in the `for` loop in your version.

Comment: I would probably just use a `while` loop for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You shall not increment the iterator when you reassign it to the return of `erase`, as you'll effectively skip one element. Put it in an extra `else` block:

```
if (itrSchedulerList->timeEndTime == ctSyatemTime.GetTime())
{

    itrSchedulerList = gSchedulerList.erase(itrSchedulerList);          
}
else
{
  ++itrSchedulerList;
}
```

And take it out of the for-loop.